# How to convert a subversion branch to git

Tags: git, svn, branch

I'm new to git, and we just switch to git. I have a feature branch which is a checkout of the a sub directory in trunk, like trunk/abc. Now I need to create a branch in git, and incorporate all the changes back. We did convert this branch in svn to git, however, since it's not from the root directory of trunk, I can't commit or merge. So here is what I plan to do:
create a branch locally: feature_abc, locally, copy all the files from the checked out svn branch abc at the right directory level, then perform a diff and commit. But with 'git status', it seems that git is going to try to commit everything that just got copied, not just the updated files.
Or I can do a svn diff from my abc branch to the trunk version we converted to git at, then manually copy updated files over to git feature_abc, but I figure there gotta be a better way of do this.
Thanks,

David

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584675/converting-svn-to-git-how-to-get-the-branches-not-to-be-just-remote-in-the-svn) existing post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for answering my question. I actually didn't want to migrate or re-create git repository from svn. I was trying to put a svn checked out branch from a sub-directory of the trunk back to git (which I don't think git supports sub-directory checkout). What I did was: get a list of changed files by diffing the branch of interest from current trunk(master); create a new branch locally in git; copy the changed files over to the git branch; then commit. I know I'll lose history information, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at following websites.

[ProGit](http://progit.org/book/ch8-2.html)
[Waaage Blog](http://qugstart.com/blog/git-and-svn/migrate-an-svn-repository-to-git-while-maintaining-branches-and-tags-structure/)